# Сомнения в постановке запятых

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, обстоятельство

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли запятые?
*В итоге(,) на пятнадцатом году жизни(,) Грэй тайно покинул дом.*
Буду благодарна за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Я за постановку запятых.

Первое "за" — рекомендация Розенталя:

> **1.** Для смыслового выделения или для пояснения могут обособляться (выделяться запятыми) обстоятельства, выраженные существительными в формах косвенных падежей (обычно с предлогами), особенно если при этих существительных имеются пояснительные слова...

**Распространенный** обстоятельственный оборот находится **в начале** предложения (*в итоге* — когда? или почему? или по каким причинам? *на пятнадцатом году жизни* — когда именно?).

Сравните (в конце предложения запятые бы не требовались):
*В итоге Грэй тайно покинул дом на пятнадцатом году жизни.*

Второе "за" — уже имеющееся авторское предложение:
*Осенью, на пятнадцатом году жизни, Артур Грэй тайно покинул дом и проник за золотые ворота моря* (А. Грин. Алые паруса).

[Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114)

Answer (score 0):

Обособление обстоятельственного оборота *на пятнадцатом году жизни* факультативное.

Если автор не выделяет этот оборот интонацией, то он запятые не поставит:

*В итоге на пятнадцатом году жизни Грэй тайно покинул дом*.

И [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=112) написано по поводу выделения (в параграфе "Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными").

Если автор выделяет оборот интонацией или подчеркивает его с целью пояснения, то он запятые поставит:

*В итоге, на пятнадцатом году жизни, Грэй тайно покинул дом*.

В обособленном варианте оборот считается дополнительной информацией, а в необособленном — основной, которая передается вместе с другой информацией в предложении.

Comment: В итоге ставить запятые?

Comment: @Лиана Тут, как я и сказал, зависит от вашего желания. Если вы выделяете оборот интонацией, то ставьте, а если нет, то не ставьте. Решать вам.

Answer (score 0):

*В итоге, **на пятнадцатом году жизни,** Грэй тайно покинул дом.*

**РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ**

Оборот обособляется, так как является **уточняющей** информацией. "**В итоге**" — это скорее итог **рассуждений** (почему покинул), нет прямого отношения  к **возрасту.**

Таким образом, выбор делается **по семантике контекста.**

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ ВЫБРАННОГО РЕШЕНИЯ**

1. **[Ссылка на правило Розенталя:](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114)**

Пункт 1. Для **смыслового** выделения или **для пояснения** могут обособляться (выделяться запятыми) обстоятельства, выраженные существительными в **формах косвенных падежей** (обычно с предлогами), особенно если при этих существительных имеются пояснительные слова.

2. Ничего другого **для решения задачи не нужно.** Интонацией мы проверяем решение, а само решение зависит от художественной **задачи автора**. **Правило**  данном случае — это **разрешение** на факультативную постановку запятой. **Примеры** — для наглядности подобных решений.
3. **Семантический** принцип в пунктуации следует считать **ОСНОВНЫМ**, а грамматика, структура предложения **(позиция** оборота), интонация, правила, примеры **дополняют** его, но **не определяют.**
4. Если автору **по семантике** нужно обособить оборот, то он выбирает соответствующую **грамматику и структуру.**

Answer (score 0):

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ К ОТВЕТУ**

**Что случилось с форумом?** Почему здесь уже не встретишь полноценного **обсуждения** темы, **обмена мнениями**? Где люди, которые могут выбрать ответ не только по правилам и примерам? Читаю старые ответы и вспоминаю их. **Alex_ander, behemothus, М_Г, grizzly, tat** — вот кого **мне не хватает**, они-то уж сказали бы что-нибудь стоящее.

Вот эта тема. Я считаю, что выбор делается **по семантике**. Структура и интонация здесь **не помощники**, так как оба варианта (с обособлением и без него) возможны.

Но в ответе (с голосом!) **указано** правило факультативного решения, названа структура и приведен пример для сравнения. А где **семантика и пояснение**, о которых говорит Розенталь?

Мне хотелось бы действительно **обсудить тему**. Здесь речь идет о **трех принципах** русской пунктуации, поэтому она важна. Кто-нибудь из "верхнего эшелона", отзовитесь, пожалуйста. Скажите хоть что-то, **обозначьте свое мнение**.

Так что здесь важнее, **семантика или позиция оборота?**